# Placeholders added to via a str_replace

Tags: php, forms, concrete5

I am trying to make a placeholder for forms in concrete5 using a the tablelessforms addon.

So far I have enabled the form to produce placeholders for inputs using the below code. However, the textarea while displaying, the function `str_replace` does not replace and add my placeholder.

Here is the code below and a link to the site : http://79.170.44.138/holidayletmidwales.co.uk/newsite/

```
<div class="fields">

    <?php  foreach ($questions as $question): ?>
        <div class="field field-<?php  echo $question['type']; ?>">
            <?php if ($question['textarea']) {   
                      $question['textarea'] = str_replace('rows="3"', 'rows="3" placeholder="'.$question['question'].'"', $question['textarea']); 
                    echo $question['textarea'];         
                    } else { 
                       $question['input'] = str_replace('value=""', 'value="" placeholder="'.$question['question'].'"', $question['input']);
                      echo $question['input'];          
                 } ?>       
            </div>  
    <?php  endforeach; ?>

</div><!-- .fields -->
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code would be a lot easier to read, if you dont use `<?php.. ?>` around every line in a contiguous block of PHP code

Answer (score 1):

The find and replace isn't working as you're searching for `rows="3"` when the markup has `rows="5"`. A better option, rather than searching for an attribute which could change, would be to find the beginning of the tag, e.g. `str_replace ('<input', '<input placeholder="foo"', $html)` or, if possible, to extend the class generating the tags to handle placeholders as you require.

Comment: Thanks i didn't know that. I think I'll change my textarea to an input and give it rows or play around with another idea. Thanks again

Comment: What you could do which, depending what you're doing, might be easier than simulating functionality with multiple inputs, is position an element containing your placeholder text over the textarea (set to pointer-events:none) then, using JavaScript, hiding/showing it on the textarea's change event, depending whether it's got content or not.

Comment: Just to update this: I've just discovered that HTML5 actually added a placeholder attribute to textareas and I hadn't realised, so they can be used. Sorry for the misinformation.